# JOIN 2 tables, and query data from them 3 times

Tags: mysql, join, select

Basically I have 2 tables: `post_meta` and `posts`.

`post_meta` has a `post_id`, `key` and `value`:

```
post_id  key      value
6343     make     Chevy
6343     model    Volt
6794     make     Chevy
6794     model    Silverado
```

`posts` has a `post_id` and `content`:

```
post_id  content
5434     Hello World!
6343     Chevy Volt review
6794     The New Silverado
```

What I need to do is pull the model based on the make (pull all unique models with the make "Chevy").  The database isn't very big so it doesn't need to be a real fast query.  Basically the plan in my mind was to get the model of every post_id that has the `post_meta.make` "Chevy".

```
SELECT post_id FROM postmeta
WHERE key = 'make'
AND value = 'Chevy'
```

then take the post_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM postmeta
WHERE post_id = {an array of post_id's}
```

something to that extent.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to store both the make and model of a vehicle for a post, since the model sort of indicates already what the make is, doesn't it?  I mean, if 'model' is 'Silverado', then make is only ever going to be 'Chevy", no?  Never Ford or Toyota.  But that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your table structure, this should extract what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.value
FROM postmeta p1
INNER JOIN postmeta p2 ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id
WHERE p2.key = 'make'
    AND p2.value = 'Chevy'
    AND p1.key = 'model';
```

Comment: and you don't need the `DISTINCT` if the `(post_id, key)` combination is unique.

Comment: Agreed, I did take that out as well.